# Compare datetime column just year (without time-day-month) with Linq

Tags: linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to get a 2022 records. But my code is not efficient. How to compare it?

```
> var _year = "2022"; list= query.Where(x =>
> Convert.ToDateTime(x.created_time).ToString("YYYY").Equals(_year
> )).ToList();
```

Comment: That `Convert.ToDateTime` call suggests you're storing your data incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Is better not to change type to string, but get DateTime structure Year property.

Code example:

```
  var year = 2022;
  var list = query.Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.created_time).Year.Equals(year)).ToList();
```